# Firebase cause delay on website open on Angular app

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We are trying to initialize Firebase in module.ts in our web app with the code below:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  isServer: false,
  // for prerender
  host: 'http://localhost:4000',
  firebase: {
    apiKey: '{XXX}',
    authDomain: '{XXX}',
    databaseURL: '{XXX}',
    projectId: '{XXX}',
    storageBucket: '{XXX}',
    messagingSenderId: '{XXX}',
    appId: '{appID}'
  },
  apiUrl: '{XXX}',
  // apiUrl: '{XXX}',
  // apiUrl: '{XXX}'
};
```

Everything works fine in our app but on first initialize of website we are having 3-4 sec delay, because of Firebase. When we inspect the project we see:

```
https://{app_name}.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns={AppId}
```

that cause the delay and inside it there is a Firebase error:

```
// 20200929233943
// https://{app_name}.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5

{
  "error": "Internal server error."
}
```

We have AngularFire: 6.0.3, Firebase: 7.21.1, Angular/Core: 9.0.7
Tried everything but cannot fix the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This call is part of Firebase Realtime Database's handshake, but it should not be blocking the loading of your site. A delay before what?

Comment: A delay before website loads. I have also added a screenshot to my question. It is on 42nd line and 43 is the last line.

Comment: Hmm... I'd expect that call to not block other resources from loading, but you won't of course get any results from the database before that call completes. Given that it is unlikely you can do anything in code to change the time that call takes, can you describe a bit more on what problem is that your users would see from this time? For example: are you loading your main content for the site from the database, so your users don't see anything until the data is loaded?

Comment: Even user is logged in or logged out and even we do ask for any data from realtime database, we get this error. I mean, even we initialize the web app with static page, we get this error and it cause delay on website load and users don't see anything. We use Angular 9 SSR configuration. (I added another image to my post that might help)

Comment: I quickly threw an initializeApp into this jsbin (https://jsbin.com/fukoniz/edit?html,js) and don't see any call to firebaseio.com happening in the network tab when I open its output in a separate window (https://output.jsbin.com/fukoniz). I suspect the fact that you use SSR may be relevant here. Can you show a [minimal repro of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, so that I (not an Angular nor SSR expert) can give it a try?